# New table values are not included in excel calculations

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-tables

I have created a table in excel which contains information on licenses, and I have created a formula which adds the value of licenses purchased in the last 30 days. The following code seems to do the trick:

```
=SUMIF(LicenseList[Purchase date], ">="&(today()-30), LicenseList[EURvalue])
```

My only problem is, that when I add new data into my table, it is not included in the result!

This is just one calculation which doesn't work - it seems that all of the calculations which are referencing the particular table, are not getting updated (I have naturally tested that the added values indeed do become part of the table).

Crossing my fingers for some help! :)

Comment: If it is not something simple like having Calculation set to manual, be aware that I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and, especially, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ribbon menu item Formulas > Formula Auditing > Evaluate Formula. This allows you to see the result of each step in the formula. You can also check precedents and dependents.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Seems to me to be more like a request for more information, which properly belongs as a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer - unfortunately it just confirms that I have a problem.
In the above, "today()-30" ends up being 44072. In my table it is being compared to a purchase date which is 44170, so it should be TRUE. But the value in the EURvalue column is not included in the sum.

Comment: Are you positive the new values are actually part of the LicenseList table?

Answer (score 0):

Because the data was being populated into the table by a VBA script, the format was invisibly not a date. This was required for the column to be included in the formula, and even though excel told me that the whole column was set as dates, they clearly were not. By converting the values to dates using CDate() before inputting them to the table, the formula now works.